# jQuery ajax call is not sending japanese character in headers attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am using jquery.ajax call to call my service and called like

```
$.ajax({
        url : "my/url/for/post",
        type : 'POST',
        headers : {name:"私はガラスを食べら"},
        contentType : "application/octet-stream",
        processData : false,
        async : true,
        dataType : "json",
        success : handlers.success,
        error : handlers.error
        });
```

But when I check the headers in sending request, name was not there.

Is there any other attribute I have to set to send japanese or chinese character in headers?

Comment: japanese, spanish, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `name: unescape(encodeURIComponent("私はガラスを食べら")` and try.
**encodeURIComponent()** will encode special characters and **unescape()** will decode the encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

replace content type with

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: Sorry @Rudresh, I need to upload file so I can't change it to `application/json`. And as per my knowledge, `Content-type` use for content type in Request body, not in headers data.